# Function involving argument of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function

When $t$ is an ordinate of a zero of Riemann zeta function, we define \begin{equation}
    f(t):=\frac{t}{2\pi}\log\left(\frac{t}{2\pi e}\right)+S(t)-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{48 \pi t}+\frac{7}{5760 t^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^5}\right)
\end{equation}
where \begin{equation}S(t):=\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\left( \frac{\arg\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+i(t+\delta))+\arg\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+i(t-\delta))}{2}\right)\end{equation}

**Question:** Prove that $f(t)$ is monotonically increasing function for all large enough $t$.

We know that $$S(t)=O(\log t) $$

Also we have if $T$ is not an ordinate of zero of $\zeta(s)$ then \begin{equation}
    N(T)=\frac{1}{\pi}v(T)+1+S(T)
\end{equation}
where \begin{equation}
    v(T):=-\frac{T}{2}\log \pi +\arg\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{iT}{2}\right)
\end{equation}
If $T$ coincides with the imaginary part of a zero of $\zeta(s)$, then \begin{equation}
    N(T)=\lim_{\delta\to 0^+} \frac{N(T+\delta)+N(T-\delta)}{2}
\end{equation}
So we obtain \begin{equation}
  N(T\pm \delta)=\frac{1}{\pi}v(T\pm \delta)+1+S(T\pm \delta)  
\end{equation}
So passing to the limit as $\delta$ tends to zero and using the continuity of the function $v(T)$ we get for $t$ an ordinate of zero of $\zeta(s)$ \begin{equation}
    N(t)=\frac{1}{\pi}v(t)+1+S(t)
\end{equation}
Now we have \begin{equation}
    v(t)=\frac{t}{2}\log\left(\frac{t}{2\pi}\right)-\frac{t}{2}-\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{1}{48 t}+\frac{7}{5760t^3}+...
\end{equation}
So we get by above two equations $$N(t)=\frac{t}{2\pi}\log\left(\frac{t}{2\pi e}\right)+S(t)+\frac{7}{8}+\frac{1}{48 \pi t}+\frac{7}{5760\pi t^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^5}\right) $$
So we obtain $$f(t)=N(t)-1+O\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$$
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You want to show that if $t$ is large enough and $h > 0$
then $f(t + h) - f(t) > 0$.  In your last equation, if
there is no zero between $t$ and $t+h$ then $N(t) - N(t+h) = 0$,
so $f(t + h) - f(t) = O(1/t)$.  You cannot conclude that is
positive, because $O(1/t)$ is just something bounded by a constant
over $t$.  (Probably you meant $O(1/t^5)$ at the last step, but that
does not change the point I am making.)  Even if there were no big-B term, $N(t)$ is nondecreasing, but it is not increasing.

Comment: @DavidFarmer Thank you for the comment. So we cannot have $f(t)$ increasing? So are you saying that $f(t)$ is non decreasing?

Comment: I am pointing out that $N(T)$ is nondecreasing,, and your function is basically $N(T)$.

You did not say were your problem came from. Was there an original problem which you converted into a new problem, and maybe something was lost in translation?